# How to filter in a single field using DateAdd

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, dateadd

"FollowingTrialDate" type is datetime

I want to filter between dates in a single field.

How can I do filtering in the FollowingTrialDate field within the **last fifteen days**.

If there is an error, where is it?

Best Regards,

```
SELECT C.[No],
convert(date,CaseDate,103) as ModuleDate,
convert(date,FollowingTrialDate,103) as FollowingTrialDate,
ShortDescription,
Username,
Name,
Surname,
Email,
C.[Description] as [Desc],
'Davalar' as ModuleName
FROM [LegalIT_MnemonicTEST].[dbo].[Module_Case] C 
inner join [System_User] su on C.LawyerID = su.UserID 
where CONVERT(date,FollowingTrialDate,0) 
between DATEADD(DD,-15,CONVERT(date,FollowingTrialDate,0)) and 
        DATEADD(DD,0,CONVERT(date,FollowingTrialDate,0))
```

Comment: what mean by last fifteen days ? you mean last fifteen days in the month of FollowingTrialDate ?

Comment: Firstly, FollowingTrialDate is in type of datetime, you don't need to convert to date again for comparison. Also, your condition to check if FollowingTrialDate between ( FollowingTrialDate -15 days ) and FollowingTrialDate will always be true

Comment: .. between CAST (DATEADD(DD,-15,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) and 
        CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DATE)

Comment: FollowingTrialDate is the date field. For example; I want to filter like between 05.07.2017 - 20.07.2017

Comment: "FollowingTrialDate is the date field", "FollowingTrialDate type is datetime". Which is correct? Edit the question accordingly.

Comment: FollowingTrialDate type is datetime.

Comment: how about CaseDate, is that a varchar or datetime

Comment: CaseDate type is date.
FollowingTrialDate type is datetime.

What I need is about "FollowingTrialDate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code (if the type of FollowingTrialDate is datetime specified in your db)

Notice that if your CaseDate or FollowingTrialDate is already in type 'datetime' specified in your database, you don't need to convert it into date first for output or for filtering data used in your WHERE clause

```
SELECT C.[No],
convert(datetime,CaseDate) as ModuleDate,
FollowingTrialDate,
ShortDescription,
Username,
Name,
Surname,
Email,
C.[Description] as [Desc],
'Davalar' as ModuleName
FROM [LegalIT_MnemonicTEST].[dbo].[Module_Case] C 
inner join [System_User] su on C.LawyerID = su.UserID 
where FollowingTrialDate
between DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, dateadd(dd, -15, getdate())), 0) and 
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: Should not be GetDate (), the entire operation will be in "FollowingTrialDate". So should be like (FollowingTrialDate-15 days)

Comment: but if you use condition says : `where FollowingTrialDate
between dateadd(dd, -15, FollowingTrialDate) and FollowingTrialDate` , the condition will always be true. Say your FollowingTrialDate is 20170720, it'll be always between 20170715 and 20170720

Comment: or you want to compare your CaseDate  with FollowingTrialDate ?

Comment: @Batuhan  It only make sence if 2 dates are compared, last fifteen days from one date to another one.

Comment: Sorry that my last comment have typo, it should be **it'll be always between 20170705 and 20170720**

Comment: @ProgrammingBaKa No, it will not be always between  20170705 and 20170720. I just gave an example.

it should be like FollowingTrialDate - 15 Days.  

I mean, there is no specific date. Bring up until 15 days before FollowingTrialDate

Comment: Any x is always between x-15 and x. You need the other variable, y to make  a predicate selective.

Comment: he don't know what i mean :'(. As @Serg said,  in general, what @Batuhan you want to do now is `where x between x-15 and x`

Comment: @ProgrammingBaKa Actually, I understand what you mean. All event x-15 and x

I solved the problem. Thank you for your help.